# How can I capture the artifact upload functionality on Travis CI?

Tags: travis-ci

Travis CI seems to have two different ways of uploading your build artifacts to (for example) S3:

- [A dedicated artifact uploading system](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/uploading-artifacts/)
- [A more generic deployment system](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/deployment/s3/)

I have tried both of these and they definitely work. The files get uploaded, everyone's happy... Except, how does anyone know where the build artifacts are?

Is there some way to either have Travis CI show the URLs to the uploaded artifacts, or to capture the URLs so I can do something with them myself?

Or, would the best option be to forgo the built in option and do the whole thing myself?

(I'm thinking of having a script append a link to the uploaded artifact to a big list on a very simple HTML page, though if there are other options, I'd love to hear them)

Answer (score 0):

I think that what I was *trying* to do is impossible for two reasons:

1. The artifact uploading tool doesn't appear to report the URLs it ends up with, except by logging.
2. The artifact uploading step happens dead last, after all job steps are complete. So, you can't capture it in the job itself even if you wanted to.

I ended up just calculating the URL and using it in the `after_script` step. Something like this:

.travis.yml:

```
# ...other stuff here...
after_script: ./artifact.sh
addons:
  artifacts:
    working_dir: build/libs
    paths:
      - $(ls build/libs/*.jar | tr "\n" ":")
    permissions: public-read
```

artifact.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd build/libs

TRAVIS_PATH=${TRAVIS_REPO_SLUG}/${TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER}/${TRAVIS_JOB_NUMBER}
NEWURL=https://s3.amazonaws.com/${ARTIFACTS_BUCKET}/${TRAVIS_PATH}/`ls *.jar`

cd ../..

# do something with $NEWURL here
```

Notes:

- This only works with a single output. However, you could easily add a loop if required
- You will probably need to change the `*.jar` parts, depending on your output(s)
- If the artifact fails to upload for some reason, you won't know (since this has to run before the upload happens)